# Hive hash function resulting in 0,null and 1, why?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am using hive 0.13.1 and hashing combination of keys using default hive hash function.

Something like 
      select hash (date,token1,token2, parameters["a"],parameters["b"], parameters["c"]) from table1;

I ran it on 150M rows. For 60% of the rows, it hashed it correctly. For the remaining rows, it gave 0. null or 1 as hash. I looked at the rows which resulted in bad hashes, I don't see anything wrong with the rows. What could be causing it?

Comment: Maybe you could supply an example of a hash that is not doing that you want it to.  Its going to be hard to answer the question as is.

Answer (score 0):

The hash function returns 0 only when all supplied arguments are blank or null.

If you are familiar with Java then you may check implementation of [hash function](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-exec/0.7.1-cdh3u3/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFHash.java).

The hash function internally uses `ObjectInspectorUtils.hashCode` to get the hashCode for the supplied fields, use below java code snippet to test manually this issue:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
public class TestHash 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( ObjectInspectorUtils.hashCode(null,PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector) );
        System.out.println( ObjectInspectorUtils.hashCode(new Text(""),PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector) );
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies required to run above program:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```