# Hive: hash function unique values

Tags: hive

In context with the below discussion, can someone confirm if the hash function would always result with unique integer value, say for millions of account numbers, and the same number would not repeat again?

[Hive hash function resulting in 0,null and 1, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617437/hive-hash-function-resulting-in-0-null-and-1-why)

Comment: Hash function may be not unique for any dataset. Collisions are quite possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash function should not be assumed to be a unique id/key generator. There are chances of collision (getting duplicates). Check this link for detailed explanation http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/